# Silex application before middleware cancel route

Tags: php, middleware, silex

I can't found the way to cancel the action inside a "Before Middleware" and send the response to the cliente without execute the controller.

For example:

```
$app->before( function( Request $request ) {
    // Do something here
    // ...
    // Here sent the response to the client and don't execute the controller
}});
```

Is possible?

**One example**

This code works fine. I'm looking for another solution using the framework built-in methods. If no possible, no problem.

```
$app->before( function( Request $request ) {
    // Do something here
    // ...

    header( 'Content-Type: application/json' );

    echo json_encode( array(
        'message' => 'Invalid token'
    ) );

    http_response_code( 400 ); // This code return Bad Request to client
    exit; // Cancel the rest of the framework
}});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to cancel your request immediately and return a 400 response make use of exceptions. In your case the user is unauthorized so something like 401 would fit.

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernelInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\UnauthorizedHttpException;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

$app->match('/', function () use ($app) {
    $app->before(function (Request $request) {
        $loggedIn= false;

        if (!$loggedIn) {
             throw new UnauthorizedHttpException(null,'unauthorized',null,Response::HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED);
        }
    });
});

$app->error(function (\Exception $e, Request $request, $code) {
    $message = strlen($e->getMessage()) > 0 ? $e->getMessage() : null;
    switch ($code) {
        case Response::HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED:
            $response = new Response($message, Response::HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED);
            break;
        default:
            $response = new Response($message, Response::HTTP_NOT_FOUND);
            break;
    }
    return $response;
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. But my intention is cancel the request returning to the client an 4XX status code. With this method the result is a status code 200 with a body generated by other controller. Perhaps my idea is incorrect or the approach is invalid.

Comment: if you wanna step out at any point and return 4xx code, use exceptions. I edited my answer.

Comment: Horst Jahns, Thanks for your help. Your solution is perfect for my approach. Regards

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the [official documentation](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.0/middlewares.html#short-circuiting-the-controller)? From the middleware docs:

> **Short-circuiting the Controller**
>
> If a before middleware returns a Response object, the request handling is short-circuited (the next middleware won't be run, nor the route callback), and the Response is passed to the after middleware right away:

```
$app->before(function (Request $request) {
  // redirect the user to the login screen if access to the Resource is protected
  if (...) {
      return new RedirectResponse('/login');
  }
});
```

If you return a Response object it should work and not call the controller.

Comment: Yes i already checked the documentation, but, in this case, the RedirectResponse send a 302 response to client and redirect to another contoller.

In my case, i need return a 4XX status code without any redirection.

Comment: Can you share your code then? (edit your question and post some code)